# Getting failed to read HTTP message, while trying to use put with resttemplate

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I am learning spring boot. And while updating a rest service below with resttemplate

```
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

//        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());
//        restTemplate.getMessageConverters().add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());


        HttpHeaders httpHeaders = restTemplate.headForHeaders("http://localhost:8080/getallblade");

        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<HttpMessageConverter<?>>();
        messageConverters.add(new FormHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Arrays.asList(MediaType.ALL));

        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2XmlHttpMessageConverter());

        messageConverters.add(converter);  
        restTemplate.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        BladeView blade  = new BladeView();
        blade.setBladeId(id);
        blade.setAppStatus(false);
        blade.setOperStatus(false);
        blade.setPowerStatus(powerstatus);


        HttpEntity<BladeView> requestUpdate = new HttpEntity<>(blade, httpHeaders);

        restTemplate.exchange("http://localhost:8080"+"/addd", HttpMethod.PUT, requestUpdate, Void.class);
```

I have tried many version of the above code with put instead of exchange but getting the same error as below:

```
Failed to read HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.ArrayList out of START_OBJECT token
 at [Source: java.io.PushbackInputStream@696b5835; line: 1, column: 1]
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 400 null
...................
at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:539)
    at com.rhevm.server.COTSSERVER.updatePowerStatus(COTSSERVER.java:102)
```

These are my controller,services and model

```
@RequestMapping(value="/addd",method=RequestMethod.PUT,consumes = "application/json", produces = "application/json")
    public void add(@RequestBody List<BladeView> bladeView) {
         System.out.println(bladeView);
         bladeViewService.add(bladeView);
    }




public void add(List<BladeView> bladeView) {
         baldeViewRepository.save(bladeView);
     }


@Entity
@Table(name="bladeview")
public class BladeView {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer bladeId;
```

Could you please guide as I am not able to solve this from days.

Answer (score 0):

you can go throw like this

```
  HttpHeaders httpHeaders = restTemplate.headForHeaders("http://localhost:8080/getallblade");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

        HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(jsonRequest, headers);

        BladeView blade  = new BladeView();
        blade.setBladeId(id);
        blade.setAppStatus(false);
        blade.setOperStatus(false);
        blade.setPowerStatus(powerstatus);
        ArrayList<BladeView> list = new ArrayList();
        list.add(blade)

        ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
        String jsonRequest = jsonObjectMapper.writeValueAsString(blade);
        restTemplate.put(uri, entity);
```